# i am trying to write cron job which has to be excute monthly i had tried but my code is working for only for minute/hour not for month

Tags: cron

public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException
    {// Configure job using Quartz.
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TriggerJob.class).withIdentity("testJob").build();
System.out.println("Job created....................");
// specify the running period of the job
CronTrigger trigger =TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("triggerName", "groupName").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 51 4 5 1/1 ?")).build(); System.out.println("getCronExpression() = "+ trigger.getCronExpression());
        // CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(3, 30))
        System.out.println("Trigger created.................");
        SchedulerFactory scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = scheduler.getScheduler();
        sched.start();
        sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
        sched.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Job scheduled...................");

```
}
public class TriggerJob implements Job
```

{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException
    {
       JobKey jobKey = arg0.getJobDetail().getKey();
       System.out.println("jobKey = " + jobKey.toString());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Call the EHCache loading mechanism once in every day.
        System.out.println("Job execution started on - " + calendar.getTime());
        // do write ur logic
        System.out.println("****************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println(" Insert Records");
        System.out.println("****************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Job execution completed on - " + calendar.getTime());
    }
}

Console OutPut:
Job created....................
Trigger created.................
getCronExpression() = 0 50 3 4 * ?
219 [main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
234 [main] INFO org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
313 [main] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
313 [main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.1.7 created.
329 [main] INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
329 [main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.7) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

329 [main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
329 [main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.7
329 [main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Job scheduled...................

Comment: give more detail about your problem, and please format your code and error(if you had described, really your question is not readble)

Answer (score 0):

**@monthly** runs the job once a month, on the 1st, at 12:00am. In standard cron syntax this is equivalent to: 0 0 1 * *.

Comment: I am not pretty sure abut what you are asking ... but I hope this is what you are looking for